# Google Drive UI Integration, Submit Failed

Tags: google-drive-api

I am doing an integration with Google Drive user interface. However when I submit the form for doing so I get this message (with no feedback on the error):

[image: screenshot]

This is the form as it was when I send it:

[image: form values]

I have tried sending it from an incognito tap, other browsers, other IPs, other accounts.....
Is there anithing I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the open url has to return status 200. My url required auth and so it returned 403

Answer (score 0):

I have entered the wrong MIME Type. That's why it was failing to submit. It seems everything that has been entered in that form has to be absolutely correct. Otherwise, it will fail to submit. The problem is, in the error dialog, the actual error has not been mentioned which is creating confusion.

For correct MIME Type I had followed this:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem but it seems to be a permissions error cause when I open the console I get a couple of 500 and 403 errors. Try contacting support.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. This really should be a comment. If you don't have a solution, please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Saddly I already went to support, but they told me they couldnt help me. It seams that the Google Drive Api team has no support team.